# combine jquery load with php and sql

Tags: php, jquery, sql, load

http://alexanderkap.esy.es/Server%20Side%20Assesment/

Hi i am trying to load each category in the example above using jquery load function. What i want to achieve is somehow tell which category is clicked so in the loaded document i can execute the correct query and display it in the space

Comment: Please show your code and what you have to try

Comment: i have put a link of my website. my code right now has nothing to see i just use load function and load a php file that has an  sql query to fetch all the rows without filtering

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. If you add get variables on the end of the loaded link despite not showing up in your url bar(because the loaded document displays internally) you can still process them to filter your querys. Then i also had to add return false; to the click events to avoid bubbling.